# I am implementing autocomplete textbox in asp.net using json and am getting Object xml http request. I have referred one blog to implent

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, json, web-services

I am implementing autocomplete textbox in asp.net using json and am getting Object xml http request error . I have referred one blog to implement that is http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/08/using-jquery-autocomplete-with-aspnet.html, could you plase let me know where I am doing wrong. I have added correctly as per the reference site. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you better describe the error and show us some code?

Comment: Using con As New SqlConnection(" Data Source=connctionstring;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=dbname")
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("select Title from Products where Title LIKE '%'+@SearchText+'%'", con)
                con.Open()
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", username)
                Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While dr.Read()
                    result.Add(dr("Title").ToString())
                End While
                Return result
            End Using

Comment: It sounds like your backend webservice is expecting an xml request.  Please make sure to make an asmx on the class you need [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] on the functions you need  [WebMethod]
 [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString = false)]

Comment: Some syntax issues here , could you please help me out with vb.net code  <WebMethod()> _ [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString = false)]

Comment: am mentioning the format at js blocks like   $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "WebService2.asmx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                    data: "{'username':'" + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function(result) {
                        alert(result);
                    }
                });

Comment: But no luck. I appreciate if could help me to solve out these